# Why gcc garbage collection behave differently for initialized global variables and uninitialized global variables?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, garbage-collection

Consider the following program :-

```
int busy[53] = { 1,2} ;
int barra[50]  = {4,5};

int main(void)
{
    int bb;
    while (1)
    {
        bb = barra[3];
    }
}
```

I compile the above program using gcc with arguments "-Wl,--gc-sections -fdata-sections" and while debugging I found that compiler/linker didn't allocate any memory for array busy, because this array is not used anywhere in the application and If I remove the line in infinite while loop, GC dint allocate any memory for barra array also.

Then I changed the same program and made the busy and barra uninitialized arrays like following -

```
int busy[53];
int barra[50];
```

Now I compiled the new program with the same command line arguments (with line inside while loop) and when I debugged, found that the compiler/linker allocated memory for both busy and barra array, not just barra. And If I remove the line in infinite while loop and re compiled, GC dint allocate any memory for both arrays, same as initialized array.

So I'm curious why compiler/linker/GC (not sure which one is doing it) allocate memory for both uninitialized arrays when only one array is used in program ?

Same case init arrays works as expected as it only allocate memory for the array which has been used in program.

Is it a bug or some tweak for variables in bss ?

GCC used - 4.9.0 20140319

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the optimizer is not a garbage collector, they're different concepts.

Comment: @Happington But it can be seen as garbage collection as well. Although the term is used normally for memory clean-up, the image fits here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but probably `-fdata-sections` only applies to the "real" data sections, not to the bss sections.

So essentially,

```
int busy[53] = { 1,2} ;
int barra[50]  = {4,5};

int ubusy[53];
int ubarra[50];
```

puts each `busy` and `barra` into their own section, but still creates one bss section containing both `ubusy` and `ubarra`.

The linker thus sees that `busy` is unused and discards it, but `bss` is used (even if not in entirety) and is thus kept.

Comment: While possible, have you actually tried compiling the OP's code?  I can't replicate the behaviour where ubusy and ubarra both get allocated.  Every time I compile it it (correctly) only allocates for ubarra.

Comment: Disregard that, it has to do with my gcc setup.

Comment: When checked the map file generated (-Wl,Map=name.map), ubusy and ubarra (uninit variables) are stored in a section named Common as you said. Can we call it a compiler bug ?